# .NET Core Web API async data return

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to handle returning data to APi client in GET HTTP response in asynchronous manner but with no luck so far.

My code :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Server.Database;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server.Controllers
{
    //[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DBContext _context;

        public UserController(DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("/Users")]
        public async Task<IAsyncResult> GetUsers()
        {
            using (_context)
            {
                // how to properly return data asynchronously ? 
                var col = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("/Users/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByID(Int32 id)
        {

            using (_context)
            {
                //this is wrong, I don't knwo how to do it properly
                //var item = await new ObjectResult(_context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.IDUser == id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I would like to handle GET request asynchronously by returning all users and in another method single user by his ID. I don't know if I need `ObjectResult`class as well but I need to respons with JSON object to the client. Someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Firstly, `using DbContext` is a bad idea, its better to register it in `Startup`, secondly, try to return `Json`, something like this: `return Json(await _context.Users.ToListAsync());`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Yuriy N. 
The problem with `Json(await _context.Users.ToListAsync())` is that I have `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'System.IAsyncResult'` error.

Comment: I've answered about that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here, try this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Server.Database;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server.Controllers
{
    //[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DBContext _context;

        public UserController(DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("/Users")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
        {
            return Json(await _context.Users.ToListAsync());            
        }

        [HttpGet("/Users/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByID(Int32 id)
        {
            return Json(await new _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.IDUser == id));          
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that in `GetUsers` you must return `IActionResult`, not `IAsyncResult`.